# C# Razor Core 3.1/6 List CSHTML

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor

Opening a code block within the CSHTML should allow for normal C# code to work.

Using VS2022 on my .Net Core Project (Razor) intellisense seems to pick up HTML elements when opening the angle brackets for the LIST collection type when it should be TYPES in C#.

In another project where nothing seems to have been different in the project the LIST seems to be working there properly.

[image]

Comment: Image updated on description

Answer (score -1):

If you introduce a new variable, you need to wrap it into a code block:

```
@{
     List<string> surveyAnswers = new List<string>();
     var text = "Hello World!";
}
```

Using these values within html is then possible without the brackets:

```
<div>@text</div>
```

Comment: It is already part of a block with the @ symbol and brace. I also have tried it within the foreach loop

Comment: If you are within the block already, you dont need another @ symbol.

Comment: Even without the @symbol the same issue is there. Its showing HTML elements

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour. Maybe it helps to restart VS or reset intellisense settings.

Comment: Its occurring within the foreach loop block. But now with the normal block of code inside @{} it shows the list fine

Comment: [Comment] MS and VS haven't got Razor "Linting" right yet, so I'm not surprised.  I forever wait on the next update in hope!  Problems seem not to be repeatable and are often cured by renaming/creating copy objects or restarting.

Comment: Weirdly enough when I am in the foreach loop that is where the issue occurs. In the normal block which begins with the @ and brace that does not happen it correctly lists out the types available in intellisense and not.

So the fix for me is putting the code inside an IF block where I am saying:

if(answers != ""){

List<survey_answer surveyAnswer =          Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PaymentsAdmin.classes.Model.TenancyNew>>(tenancyByAddressJSON);

}

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Maybe your right there seems to be an issue with VS and not my logic. Why would I want html elements showing up when I am trying to set up types against a List object.